# Python kivy. [8620]Failed to execute script main. When running exe file, works perfectly as .py

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, exe

https://github.com/taseenuddin/Kobe-Quiz/tree/main

Here are my files, there is no .kv file. My .py file runs on virtual env and pycharm with no problems. My code is pretty atrocious, first time really app developing on python, I just wanted it to work. And yes all dist files and images and music folders were moved to the root directory of my app. Went through tons of fixes and multiple videos but still the exe is not running. And it always says failed to execute script main.py and unable to recreate a playbin.

Here is all of my project files. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l9oKipKLYnylAMrwmgvAmy_y_o0lfN3H/view?usp=sharing

I caught the error in slow motion using my phone pretty blurry though.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_TwNKxjhMTU1tbTuk05VUGwUP9sZdYy/view?usp=sharing

If anyone can compile the file into a setup format or help me get the exe working that would be an extreme blessing. I have 3 days until my app is due for my ap csp class and I am quite literally shitting myself because I've been trying to find my issue for the last two days and I can't reach my Professor over the spring break.

edit: Btw I am using Python 3.7.1 other versions had issues with Kivy

Comment: try adding your `music` folder to `datas`. Like `datas = [('music/*.mp3', 'music')]`

Comment: So should I add this to my spec file and rebuild it or my main,py file?

Comment: ok so I ended up adding that line of code to my spec file and rebuilt the app the error is still there but however the program runs longer but I get tons of plugin errors and it ends with failed to execute main script the compile python file works however. Here is the link, I caugh the error in slow motion.

<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hm2UfyI_1P_0ZCkjHIO2C49EuCX9ucMs/view?usp=sharing>

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-windows.html#packaging-a-video-app-with-gstreamer).